# MySQL: Create a new column with different values on a query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to make a Query that selects a date and assigns four different string values to that date on a new created field.

This is the desired result:

```
date  | classif(field not selected from other table)
---------------
date1 |  'a'
date1 |  'b'
date1 |  'c'
date1 |  'd'
date2 |  'a'
date2 |  'b'
date2 |  'c'
date2 |  'd'
```

It helps pointing that It has to be a SELECT statement. It can't be created on a procedure, and I am not able to create new or temporary tables.

Comment: I could not figure out your problem. Could you please try to be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (date, classif1, classif2) 
SELECT date, concat(classif1,' ',date), concat(classif2,' ',date)
  FROM tableY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL doesn't have a `VALUES` table, you can emulate a table that has your four values using `UNION ALL`. Your final query would look something like this:

```
SELECT table1.date, vals.val
  FROM table1
  JOIN (SELECT 'a' as val UNION ALL
        SELECT 'b' as val UNION ALL
        SELECT 'c' as val UNION ALL
        SELECT 'd' as val) vals
```